# html tags not working inside uib-tooltip

Tags: angularjs, html

I am using `tootltip` and `trusashtml` also but text is appearing as a string its not parsing into html.

**HTML:**

```html
<label uib-tooltip="{{TooltipText}}"
       tooltip-enable="!showEditHours"
       for="IsAttested"
       ng-class="{'Cursor_Auto': !showEditHours}">Text</label>
```

**Controller:**

```
 $scope.ad = { 'text': 'This attestation is editable only when the  <b>   Hours of the Accounting Firm of the Issuer  </b>  section has been enabled for edit. Please click on the Edit <b> Hours of the Accounting Firm of the Issuer </b>  button.' };
 $scope.TooltipTextAttestationFinalName = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.ad.text);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

The first is to use the directive `uib-tooltip-html` which according to the [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tooltip) takes an expression that evaluates to a html string. This is probably what you're looking for:

```
<label uib-tooltip-html="TooltipText"
   tooltip-enable="!showEditHours"
   for="IsAttested"
   ng-class="{'Cursor_Auto': !showEditHours}">Text</label>
```

The other is to the `uib-tooltip-template`, which takes an expression that resolves to a template path.

Comment: Thanks, i was using expressions inside uib-tooltip-html  that was the reason thanks again.

Comment: What is the reason behind this??

Comment: The `uib-tooltip-html` directive takes an angular expression as input, but `{{someVar}}` actually evaluates the expression before passing it to the directive, so the directive only get's a string and tries to evaluate it again (and fails). As an example if you have declared `$scope.someVar = 'This is a string'` and passes it like this `uib-tooltip-html='{{someVar}}'`, then behind the scenes, the tooltip directive tries to use it somewhat like this: `$scope['This is a string']`, but that clearly wouldn't work. It's a bit difficult to explain clearly in a comment. :-)

Comment: Great. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<label uib-tooltip-html="{{TooltipText}}"
       tooltip-enable="!showEditHours"
       for="IsAttested"
       ng-class="{'Cursor_Auto': !showEditHours}">Text</label
```

Controller

```
$scope.ad = { 'text': 'This attestation is editable only when the  <b>   Hours of the Accounting Firm of the Issuer  </b>  section has been enabled for edit. Please click on the Edit <b> Hours of the Accounting Firm of the Issuer </b>  button.' };
 $scope.TooltipTextAttestationFinalName = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.ad.text);
```

Comment: I tried before actually , when i use html nothing is coming at all